# iText InvalidPdfException Rebuild failed: '>' not expected at file pointer

Tags: itext

We're trying to concatenate many dynamically generated pdf together using PdfSmartCopy as follow

```
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, outputStream);

    document.open();

    for (PdfReader reader : list) {
         int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
        // page numbers start at 1
        for (int page = 1; page <= n; page++) {
            copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, page));
        }

        copy.freeReader(reader);
        reader.close();
    }

    document.close();
```

Once in a while, we keep getting this exception `InvalidPdfException: Rebuild failed: '>' not expected at file pointer 65537; Original message: Invalid object number. at file pointer`

Or `InvalidPdfException: Rebuild failed: Dictionary key 0 is not a name. at file pointer 65536`

Have anyone encountered this before?

Comment: This only happens when iText encounters a PDF with invalid syntax. Please fix the PDF and the problem will disappear.

Comment: I opened the pdf file using RUPS itext 5.5.8 (the document was created using itext 5.5.7 btw), but RUPS doesn't really show any problem

Comment: @timpham Please share a PDF with that issue for reproduction of the issue and analysis of the cause. (The file pointer values in your exception are suspiciously near to the 2^16 barrier, by the way; this might hint towards a buffering problem, e.g. during creation of the problematic PDF.)